# A diagonal generating function for Fibonacci: Part II

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

In my earlier [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350882/a-special-type-of-generating-function-for-fibonacci), I mentioned although we have for the Fibonacci numbers that
$$F_n=[x^n]\left(\frac1{1-x-x^2}\right),$$
is there a function $F(x)$ such that $F_n=[x^n]\left(F(x)\right)^n$?

Several people offered their responses and I thank Henri Cohen, AccidentalFourierTransform, Fedor Petrov, Richard Stanley, and Ira Gessel, and Aaron Meyerowitz for that. The general agreement is that there seems to be "no closed formula" or "explicit formula".

**Notation.** Let $[x^ny^n]G(x,y)$ be the coefficient of $x^ny^n$ in the Taylor series of $G(x,y)$.

This time, I would like to increase the number of variables and ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? There is an explicit generating function such that
> $$F_n=[x^ny^n](G(x,y))^n.$$

Comment: Define $G(x,y) := F(xy)$?

Comment: I will add "explicit".